# cachingactivitymapper usage example

Tags: gwt, history

We implemented a GWT app using a MVP pattern.
Now we wanted to use cachingactivitymapper in that application.

I searched on the web for how to use this. I couldnt get anything.

Can anyone please provide me the example of using cachingactivitymapper.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily set up one example via Spring Roo ( if you dont get trippped by spring roo related errors). Reference  - http://gwtsts.blogspot.in/2011/03/part-iii-exploring-roo-generated-gwt.html

Some other example GitHub projects -

```
https://github.com/ashtonthomas/beans
https://github.com/ashtonthomas/gwt-seminar
```

Comment: This answer falls short of "providing an example".